# Are the intro, post-scriptum, and post-post-scriptum in my answer acceptable, or should they be removed?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Game Development Stack Exchange post: [2D isometric pixel art technique](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/169087/2d-isometric-pixel-art-technique/171608#171608)

I began my answer with the following intro:

> First off, I want to highlight this excerpt from a comment to your original problem (I'm new here so if this violates whatever aesthetic standard, let me know and I can edit this bit out):
>
> > We generally can't answer "How did the developers of Game X implement feature Y?" . . . we can answer "I'm having this specific problem with the strategy I'm using so far — how can I fix/improve it?"
>
> ---
>
> MY ANSWER TO YOUR QUESTION AS IT IS STATED RIGHT NOW: (12:34pm eastern standard time)

And I concluded my answer with the following post-scripta:

> **POST SCRIPTUM**
>
> You state you're new to art, which is totally cool! My answer involves knowledge of external programs such as Adobe Photoshop or Autodesk Maya. If you are not familiar with those programs, but are interested in learning them, AND if this project is a non-commercial personal project, let me know! I would be more than willing to assist you with further questions when I have free time.
>
> **POST POST SCRIPTUM**
>
> Again, I'd like to state I'm new to stack exchange as a whole, so let me know if I should delete this portion of my answer and I will move it to some meta forum instead, but the problem occurred here so I would like to briefly address it here. I'd just like to state that the feelings I have gotten from SE's culture and ruleset are lowkey hostile. This is a question about art, a subjective medium, and as such it may require a subjective answer. The unyeilding requirement that questions be phrased as clear-cut and logically as possible such that there is an objective and finite range of answers, while helpful in raising the quality bar of content on the site, is quite frankly ableist, or at the very least extremely offputting to me personally. If you're able to do so, please keep the tone you address other people with somewhere close in your mind as you reply to logical issues or gripes: even though we are all dealing with computers here, we ourselves are humans, and I believe the golden rule is a fairly universal benchmark for interpersonal communication. Thank's :- )

Are the intro, post-scriptum, and post-post-scriptum in my answer acceptable, or should they be removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for asking this on Meta!

Generally, questions asking "how did they do it" can be reworded as "how could I achieve this", and you can answer the question as if it was asked like that, so I think the intro, until the 'All isometric game' is not necessary.

---

> [...] IS STATED RIGHT NOW: (12:34pm eastern standard time)

Everything (questions, answers and edits) is timestamped and accessible, so there is again really no need to specify this: if there is a discontinuity between the answer and the question, users learn to check the edit log.

---

About the P.S.: It's all right to post some information that are not directly related to the question asked. As such,

> You state you're new to art, which is totally cool! My answer involves knowledge of external programs such as Adobe Photoshop or Autodesk Maya.

Is OK, as it gives tips to the user (and the future visitors) what tools could be used.

Now keep in mind that you write answers for the user who asked, *and the future visitors* to the site. The rest of the paragraph is not really relevant to them, and will not really relevant in 6 months from now, when you'll be tackling other projects. You might want to post it as a comment to the question when your rep allows it.

---

You can leave the 'POST SCRIPTUM' notice there, or you could just add an horizontal line to make it clear there is a division between the answer and the 'side notes'. We don't have rules for that.

---

About the P.P.S.: Yes, this should be a post on meta, not part of an answer. If you have an issue with a specific comment, question or answer on the 'main site' (https://gamedev.stackexchange.com), you should "Ask" about it on the meta site (like you just did), and you should link to the relevant post, with quoting the relevant text, if appropriate, as these can be harder to retrieve if they get deleted.

Comment: i know it's frowned upon to say "thanks!!!" but i don't have enough rep for my upvotes to be visible (i despise the rep = privs system, but that's a discussion for a separate meta post)... so Thank You!!! This was a really good response, and it answered my question effectively without making me feel any shame. Answers like this make the culture more positive by ratio! :- )

Comment: Saying thanks is not _really_ frowned upon. It's just that the vote system is there for that, often. And "thanks" comments are often deleted, but no worries :) I think "culture" on gamedev.se is a bit more welcoming to new users than what there is on SO. Glad I could help :)